# How to get key (index) value of a textbox in array textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want a jQuery function or javascript that alert the index and the value of array textboxes : e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="1" onblur="javascriptfunction(this.value,this.index)" />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="foo" onblur="javascriptfunction(this.value,this.index)" />

<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="banana" onblur="javascriptfunction(this.value,this.index)" />
```

Whenever mouse moves for example from the first input I have this alerted (1,0) and second is (foo,1) and so on. I couldn't find the function that does that. Please help.

Comment: yes i want to navigate the index of the current textbox

Comment: im just giving an example of what i want to do ! how to get the index or the key of that selected textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var textboxes = $('input[name="textbox[]"]');

textboxes.on('blur', function() {
    var index = textboxes.index( this );
    alert( this.value + ', ' + index );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="1"  />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="foo"  />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="banana"  />
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, but still the code works for only first text box but not the rest ! im using this code to clone the table tr :

Comment: <script>
    $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
        var $tr  = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');

        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $clone.find(':text').removeAttr("readonly");
        $tr.after($clone);
    });
    $("input.tr_clone_remove").live('click', function() {
        var $tr  = $(this).closest('.tr_clone').remove();

    });



</script>

Comment: maybe that what caused the problem ?

Comment: It might be helpful if you created a jsfiddle ..... which would be much easier to troubleshoot. What do you think?

Comment: You are genius Man !! thank you from the bottom of my heart !!

Comment: How do i make a function for that purpose on your last fiddle example ? so i dont have to see its execution all the time ! i need to use in some special cases

Comment: You probably need to add a class to the input elements you want to target. Then you'll use that class in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) like

```js
$('input').blur(function(){
  alert($(this).val() + ',' + ($(this).index()-1));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="foo" />

<input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="banana" />
```

**Update**

To target certain elements or have this in a named function, first, put identifiers on your elements such as a class `my-class`. Then, make a named function and pass it to the jQuery blur function

```js
$('.my-class').blur( alertIndexAndVal );

function alertIndexAndVal(){
  alert($(this).val() + ',' + ($(this).index()-1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-class" type="text" name="textbox[]" value="1" />
<input class="my-class" type="text" name="textbox[]" value="foo" />

<input class="my-class" type="text" name="textbox[]" value="banana" />
```

Comment: How to make a function for that ? its not necessary that all textboxes send values and indexes ! thank you for your great contribution

Comment: @kallokallo, do you mean you want to have only certain inputs do this? Or do you just want to use a named function like function getValAndIndex(){...}?

Comment: Thank you Ammar ! the problem is im using jquery clone to duplicate rows that have array input fields ! your code only works on the first input and doesnt work on the rest of the input text fields that have the same name ! so i decided to try to broadcast the index for each element (textbox) using a function that i should call every time i generate a new input text field .. like this <input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="foo" onblur="javascriptfunction(this.value,this.index)" /> is that possible ?

Comment: @kallokallo, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @kallokallo, but note the fiddle above uses a newer version of jquery. Let me know if you cannot use a newer version

Comment: try to add 5 rows ! click on any in the middle you have indexx of (-1) !!

Comment: Please change it if you that would give the needed output im a lil noob in javascript and jquery

Comment: Thank yo Ammar ! got what im looking for !

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post a javascript solution which to be honest attempts to do something like the index function of jquery although i think jquery function might be better.

```js
var getIndexValue = function (e) {
    var children = e.parentElement.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] == e) {
            alert("Index: " + (i+1) + ", Value: " + e.value);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="one" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
    <input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="two" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
    <input type="text" name="textbox[]" value="three" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
</div>
```

Index: (i+1)

Value: (e.value);